# Start two node scripts in parallel in different terminal tabs via .sh script

Tags: node.js, shell, unix, terminal, sh

The executable `start.sh` script below runs two commands in parallel. It gets the job done, but I only see output from the latter command and both of these are "active" node scripts that constantly output information based on project code changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

../../node_modules/.bin/tsc --watch | 
./node_modules/.bin/react-native start --reset-cache;
```

Is a way to run these together via same script *i.e.* just running `start.sh` in terminal, but to run each command in a separate tab or window?

Comment: This Q. seems more about [concurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) [*pipelines*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) than [parallel processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with xterm. You need to adjust depending what terminal and bash you use. I know for sure for example that gnome-terminal does not support `-t` flag, so you need to omit it.

```
// a.sh
#! /bin/bash
echo "Hello from a"

// b.sh
#! /bin/bash
echo "Hello from b"

// main.sh
#! /bin/bash
xterm -t "proc a" -e "./a.sh" &
xterm -t "proc b" -e "./b.sh"
```